# Append declaration to XML file

Tags: sql, xml, t-sql

Creating XML out of data in Database  by calling proc with bcp as

```
SET @SQL= 'bcp "exec dbo.proc" queryout '+ @FileName +' -w -r -t  -Sdd\SQL2005 -T '
```

(proc produced below)
Everything is fine => creates XML as desired.
Now task is to Add Declaration to this XML (`<?xml version="1.0" ?>`)

How can this be achieved either in below proc or concating XML with other file (containing the declaration)

```
SELECT  ( SELECT TOP 1
                    ShiftDate AS "ShiftDate",
                    Shift AS "Shift"
          FROM      [TableName]
        FOR
          XML PATH(''),
              TYPE
        ),
        ( SELECT    EquipmentId AS "WasheryProductionDetails/EquipmentCode",
                    'n/a' AS "WasheryProductionDetails/ActivityCode",
                    'n/a' AS "WasheryProductionDetails/ReasonCode",
                    Parentmaterial AS "WasheryProductionDetails/WasheryFeed/MaterialCode",
                    ParentStockpile AS "WasheryProductionDetails/WasheryFeed/ROMStockpileCode",
                    CAST(ParentTonnes AS DECIMAL(18, 4)) AS "WasheryProductionDetails/WasheryFeed/FeedTonnes",
                    ChildMaterial AS "WasheryProductionDetails/WasheryOutput/MaterialCode",
                    ChildStockpile AS "WasheryProductionDetails/WasheryOutput/ProductStockpileCode",
                    CAST(ChildTonnes AS DECIMAL(18, 4)) AS "WasheryProductionDetails/WasheryOutput/ProductTonnes"
          FROM      [TableName]
        FOR
          XML PATH(''),
              TYPE
        )
FOR     XML PATH(''),
            ROOT('WasheryProduction')
```

Thanks

Comment: Voted to close as "Not a real question".

Comment: Why? Its asking a TSQL question?
RMDUSSA: Could you rephrase the question with  more info as to what error messages you get.

Answer (score 2):

[This page](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/fr-FR/sqlxml/thread/17fdee4a-06ab-4bbb-876c-52adca018ca0) suggests that you need to hard-code the declaration:

```
SELECT

'<?xml version="1.0" ?>'

+
SELECT  ( SELECT TOP 1
... rest of your code goes here...
```

EDIT: Changed "UNION ALL" (which was pretty clearly wrong) to "+" (both taken from the linked page.)

Comment: Sorry, I have tried before and the error was All queries combined using a UNION, INTERSECT or EXCEPT operator must have an equal number of expressions in their target lists.
Thanks

Comment: You're right about UNION.  But the page that I linked to also suggests using +, which is the string concatenation operator in SQL Server:

SELECT

'<?xml version="1.0" ?>'

+
SELECT  ( SELECT TOP 1
...

Comment: Great! Its craeted the xml file but it through an error while opening
The XML page cannot be displayed 
Cannot view XML input using XSL style sheet. Please correct the error and then click the Refresh button, or try again later. 


--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

End of file reached in invalid state for current encoding. Error processing resource 'file:///C:/20090428NS.xml'. Line 1, ...

Comment: Found lot of empty spaces in the end of file,do not know how to get rid automatically while creating file. once I removed manually ,its opend fine.
Thanks

Comment: It is possible to Create XML File with concatination But it's not opening the XML file,because lot of empty spaces in XML file.
So it's not working.I have decided to create XML without declaration

Answer (score 2):

```
Declare @SQL varchar(8000)
Declare @xml xml
Declare @strXML as varchar(max)

set @xml = (select * from <tableName> for xml path(''))
set @strXML='< ? xml version = "1.0" ? >' + convert(varchar(max), @xml)

select @strXML

set @SQL ='bcp "select '''+@strXML+'''"  QueryOut "C:\xmlFile.xml" -r -w -t -T -S '

Exec master..xp_cmdshell @SQL
```

Comment: This solved problem from rmdussa, where the free space did not created any more...